# Deploying ServiceFabric apps using AzureAD Authentication

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I want to deploy apps to my service fabric using azure ad & powershell.

I've setup the required azure AD apps, but I don't know how to login to an Azure AD account programtically so it can be deployed from CD tool. It seems like this needs to be an AD user and not service principal. The COnnect-ServiceFabric cmdlet requires some sort of security token when using AzureAD and I don't know how to provide it to avoid the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are steps that you could use to get things up and running -

**1.** You need to create two app registrations in AD - the one to represent the SF cluster and the second one for the client app. You could follow the instructions here to get it done [Set up Azure Active Directory for client authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm#set-up-azure-active-directory-for-client-authentication)

As the result, you should have the next output -

> "azureActiveDirectory": {   "**tenantId**":"guid",   "**clusterApplication**":"guid",   "**clientApplication**":"guid" }

**2.** Now you could set up your SF cluster. You could either put the AD artifacts you've got from the previous step into the rm template or specify the fields in the portal. The choice is yours -

[image]

**3.** Find the app registrations created at the first step in AD, and assign to the user you are going to login with some role there.

**4.** Finally, use this example to login using AD authentication in a non-interactive mode - [Connect to a secure cluster non-interactively using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster#connect-to-a-secure-cluster-non-interactively-using-azure-active-directory).

Here is just the same but in Powershell -

```
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id"
$credentials = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential]::new($UserName, $Password)
$authContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($authority)
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($clusterApplicationId, $clientApplicationId, $credentials) 
$Token = $authResult.Result.AccessToken

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -AzureActiveDirectory -SecurityToken $Token -ConnectionEndpoint "your_cluster_name.location.cloudapp.azure.com:19000" -ServerCertThumbprint "your_server_cert_thumbprint"
```

That's basically it.

Comment: I'm able to run the powershell without the -securitytoken and login via popup and connect to the fabric cluster. However, using the powershell code above to bypass the popup with the same user, it logs in but it does not connect to the cluster, it gives:

Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : The specified credentials are invalid. Any idea? It's the same exact user.

Comment: Hmm so it seems like the acquiretoken is working and a Token is returning even if I use an incorrect password. Also, if I pass this $authResult.Result.AccessToken as the -SecurityToken value the connection works. Not sure where the disconnect is here for me, I've started a fresh powershell ISE session.

Comment: @DaveN My bad, it should've been authResult.Result.AccessToken. Sorry for that. So is it working for you? Or you still see the issue?

Comment: It works but it doesn't respect the password, I'm not sure why that is. So I can use a bad password and it still works, it does require the username to be correct though.

Comment: Any clue why the password wouldn't be respected?

Comment: @DaveN  So... you're using exactly the same code I've posted above, right? And in a brand new Powershell session, you still get a valid connection? Please, try C# code described here - [Connect to a secure cluster non-interactively using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster#connect-to-a-secure-cluster-non-interactively-using-azure-active-directory). Let's see what you will get there. Also, run Fiddler or something to verify the raw http requests. I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @DaveN I've tried to reproduce the issue. Indeed, if I change the password in the existing session I still get the token. So I'll dig around to see how to flush out the cache. But in a new Powershell window, I couldn't reproduce it - I was getting an error saying that username or password is invalid, and only when I provided a correct one it worked.

Comment: @DaveN I think I've figured it out - add the second parameter when you create AuthonticationContext as $null - $authContext = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext]::new($authority, $null). It should not use any cache then.

Comment: Awesome, that did it.. had me concerned for a bit :) Thank you!

Comment: @DaveN My pleasure