# How to create Azure service fabric cluster without security certificate for testing use?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-security

For **testing purpose**, we need to spin up Azure service fabric cluster without any security certificates.

We have already created new Azure SF cluster with self-signed certificate successfully but octopus cant connect to new Azure SF cluster for package deployment due to some certificate related issues. So without certificate need to spin up new Azure service fabric cluster.

How to create Azure service fabric cluster without security certificates?

here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm
options are available to create Azure SF cluster only **with** security certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Azure, but you can create an unsecured stand-alone cluster. What you can do, is use self-signed certificates to deploy the cluster, and a[dd Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-create-template#add-azure-ad-configuration-to-use-azure-ad-for-client-access) for client access to the management API's.

> FabricClient and FabricGateway perform a mutual authentication. During
> Azure AD authentication, Azure AD integration provides a client
> identity to the server, and the server certificate is used by the
> client to verify the server's identity. For more information about
> Service Fabric certificates, see X.509 certificates and Service
> Fabric.

This way, you can use a [Service Principal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61914877/5946937) to authenticate.